# SAS import excel numeric column as text

Tags: sas

I have an excel file where i have a column formatted as 'General'. It holds numeric values but i want it imported as text.

When I use:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= test DATAFILE= "C:\file"
            DBMS=xlsx REPLACE;
     GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

Sometimes it is imported as number, sometimes as text. How can I always import it as text? I am using sas 9.4 on windows 7 and excel 2010.

Even this does not work...it does not change the datatype:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= test DATAFILE= "C:\data.xlsx"
            DBMS=excel  REPLACE;
            DBDSOPTS= "DBTYPE=(Employee_No='CHAR(3)')";
     GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

Comment: DBSASTYPE is one way, but SAS doesn't provide an easy way to specify the formats. There is a suggestion in to add an option to import everything as character in the SASware Ballot suggestions. The usual workaround is to convert it to CSV and import the file with full control.

Comment: Thank you. Will DBSASTPYE work with xlsx? The example show dbms=excel

Comment: Do you have the Excel SAS/ACCESS engine? If not, can you install SAS PC File Server? This will give you libname access.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can do it using PCFILES approach instead of XLSX.

```
libname test pcfiles path=  'c:\_localdata\demo.xlsx';

data want;
set test.'Sheet1$'n (dbsastype=Random=char8);
run;

libname test;
```

Comment: Thank you. What is the Random? Can i specify a column name?

Comment: It was a variable I created for testing, replace it with your variable name.

Comment: It says install pc files server. I cannnot install it, it is a prod machine. Can you see my EDIT?

Comment: That's weird, with a full installation I'd assume you have that component. Do you have it? Is it possible it's not turned on?